# System of Linear D.E's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Question
Consider $x^{'}$ = ax and $y^{'}$ = $-y$

Where a is a real number strictly less then -1

Show that all Trajectories become parallel to the y-direction as t goes to Infinity and parallel to the x direction as t goes to negative Infinity.

So im a bit Confused here, i think that if we take $y^{'}/x^{'}$ = $-y/ax$ where a is always negative. so i want to re write it as b=$-a$

Yielding  $y^{'}/x^{'}$ = $y/bx$   what im confused about is there no time in here? doesn't $dy/dt$ * $dt/dx$ = $dy/dx$ ? if it does there's no time parameter.

Clearly i have no idea what im doing, and this is nothing like the other examples we have done in class or in our homework. can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write this as a 2x2 matrix and find the characteristic polynomial, you get:

$$\lambda^2 + (1-a)\lambda -a = 0$$

This gives us two real and distinct negative eigenvalues (since your conditions do not allow $a = -1$).

So, for example, solve the CP for $a = \{-2, -3, -4\}$. The eigenvalues are negative, real and distinct.

How does that make the phase portrait behave? Plot the solutions and see the behavior for all three.

**Update**

If you write,

$x' = ax +0y$

$y' = 0x -1y$

This can be written as a matrix $A$:

$$A = \pmatrix{a & 0  \\
 0 & -1}
$$

Then, solve $|A -\lambda I|= 0$.

Got it?

Regards

Comment: Ah, a stable node with all ivp flowing to 0,0 along parabolas with the only fp at 0,0?  ah nvm i see it now ty im so stupid haha.
Math anything notation always confuses me.

Comment: See update for how to get the CP. Make sense?

Comment: Haha yeah i figured it out when i wrote out the matrix n solved with lambda in it. tyvm man!

Comment: You are very welcome. It is good to think about what happens when eigenvalues are positive, negative, complex with all variants and know the behaviors. This goes a long way! Regards

Comment: Great job, again, and nice to have such enthusiastic feedback, too! That's reward in and of itself!

Answer (score 0):

I thought a different approach but I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

The idea is as following: If we show that $ \frac{dy}{dx} \rightarrow \infty \text{ as } t \rightarrow \infty$, then that means the trajectories become parallel to the y-direction as $t \rightarrow \infty$ because there is a big change in the y-direction while there is a negligible change in the x-direction. But I am stuck at this point because we don't have any time variable within $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

However, intuitively I sense that since a<-1 x will decay more rapidly than y and it will eventually lead to $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to become infite because we know that $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{ax}{-y}$$ But I couldn't expressed it in a proper mathematical way.